# Liferay + JSP + AlloyUI: Button as link and submit

Tags: java, jsp, liferay, alloy-ui

I use Liferay 6.2 on JBoss 7.1.1.
Also I am using a JSP as view with AlloyUI.

I want a button as a link and as a submitter of a value to a method in the MVCPortlet class.
The link is inside a java array.
The attribute that is passed to the java method is inside a input field.

It works if I use just one of this two.
I tried to combine them but it doesn't work.
I tried this:

```
<a href="<%=unread[i][k]%>" target="_blank" >
<aui:button type="submit" />
</a>
```

It calls the method but it doesnt opens a new tab in my browser. In my browser I can see that it is a link, if I click right on it -> new tab, it opens it correctly in a new tab. But not if I just click on the button.
Second way:

```
<aui:button type="submit" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.de', '_blank', ''); return false;"/>
```

It just opens google but doesn't calls the method. Also it is not possible to get an Java attribute inside of a Javascript, but I could get the value out of a hidden input field. But still there would be the problem that it doesn't call the method.

Comment: Writing js function(to be fired on click of anchor tag) which will submit the form would be better option. Also keep your form and portlet:actionURL part out of for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to get on with the second solution.
The first mistake was `return false;` in my onclick param, so I deleted it.
Then the submit function works as usual.
The next problem was to access a Java variable inside the javascript onclick method, so I used EL and JSTL to get it work:

```
<c:set var="url" scope="session" value="<%=unread[i][k]%>"/>
<aui:button type="submit" onclick="window.open('${url}', '_blank', '');" />
```